Lua function: 'type', recreated in Luau
I need help with CheckType. How can I make it check: Enum. (Enum is a userdata, but it doesn't work; Enum is in Luau.) (This is me asking for help in the Language: Luau (Roblox))
When I test Enum, it gives me a string because it turns into the string: "Enums"
Doing type(Enum) -- Output: userdata.
I want my own code to be as accurate as possible to the original type function.
I also need help with a better newproxy, it just doesn't feel the same way as the original Lua 5.1 one.
local proxy = {}

newproxy = newproxy or function(bool)
   if bool then
      setmetatable(proxy, {
                      __index = {}
      })
   end
   return proxy
end

function CheckType(a)
   local s, e = pcall(function()
         return a.Archivable and (string.match(tostring(a), "^(.-):") == nil)
   end)

   local _nil = ((a == nil) and "nil")
   local Instance = ((s and e ~= nil) and "Instance")
   local userdata = ((a == newproxy(true)) and "userdata")  
   local coffee = (string.match(tostring(a), "^(.-):"))
   local boolean = (((a == true) and "boolean" or (a == false) and "boolean"))  
   local number = (((tonumber(a) ~= nil and tostring(a) ~= nil) and "number"))
   local string = ((((not tostring(a) == _nil) and (not tonumber(a)))) and "string")
   local unknown = "Unknown"

   return Instance or userdata or coffee or boolean or number or string or unknown
end

print(CheckType(Enum)) -- Output: userdata (But it Outputs: string)


in your code you have the comment -- Output: userdata (But it Outputs: string) do you mean but is SHOULD output string?

Also why do you want a newproxy? it is no longer needed to do a deconstructor when the table gets GC'ed, or were you using it for something else? You may want to split that question off into it's own post.

It should print userdata, it is printing string, because Enum is converted into a string, it is converted into Enums. When printing Enum you can see that it does that. Enum is a userdata when using the type function. Also I need newproxy for userdata (In Lua 5.2 it is removed, I just wanted it to be universal if someone uses it in an newer version of Lua, that is why newproxy = newproxy or function is there.)

@Valkyrie -- now I am confused. I thought that you were writing Lual code, but now you mention portability to plain Lua. Does this code work in Lual, but not in Lua? Some clarification would be good, but it would be best to simplify: write code for one language, tell us what that language is, and edit your question appropriately.

@Nifim -- newproxy is still in Luau, I believe.

The question is pretty clear: OP wrote CheckType to behave as the built-in type function. Currently CheckType(Enum) returns "string", but it should return "userdata", the same as type(Enum). What is not clear is whether OP is running under Lua, and what version, or under Luau.

I am trying to make it run in Luau (aka Lua 5.1 Fork, Roblox). The rest of the Checks work fine.

Currently, userdata checks are Luau only, the rest work in Lua 5.2-5.4 too.
